Subtraction of doubles in c++
I have been doing some scientific computing working lot with very small and very big doubles with values in range between 1e-50 and 1e50. Nevertheless, the values never reach double limits, i.e. no overflow takes place.
While the script runs, subtracting and adding numbers is smooth, until at some point the following error appears:
adding 2 identical doubles with just different sign gives not a 0.0 and not even a 0.0000000015 or something similar, but a number, which makes absolutely no sense.
For example
double x = 1.43441e+49;
double y = -1.43441e+49;
double res = x + y;

Expected res = 0.0, but I get -5.1923e+33.
The issue appears only after the script running for a while. If I just run small script, checking the result with given doubles, it gives 0.0 as expected.
Would be glad to get any help on this issue!

Assuming you know floating point numbers have limits to their precission. There is a whole academic field dedicated to knowing what kind of numerical errors you can get (and how to limit their impact). E.g. Numerics and Error Analysis

Once you've read the linked question, I hope it will be obvious why not overflowing is different from not running out of resolution.

When I print out the values, I get x is 14344100000000000103939267041957645221155590635520.0, and y is -14344100000000000103939267041957645221155590635520.0, and res is 0.0.  Are you getting the same values?  What compiler are you using?  On what platform?  With what compiler flags?

In that particular code, the result is required to be 0. But in slightly different code it wouldn't: double x = 1.43441e+49; double res = x - 1.43441e+49;. The difference is that in the first, the value of y gets stored, and the rule is that it has to be truncated as necessary to fit in a double. In the second, 1.43441e+49 can have extra bits (perhaps 80 bits precision), and the subtraction can be done at that full precision and the result truncated to fit in a double. Welcome to the wonderful world of floating-point arithmetic.

Re “adding 2 identical doubles with just different sign”: The values are not identical. The fact that the output from printing two double values with default formatting is the same does not mean their values are the same. Default formatting does not show full precision. When you print the numbers with full precision, you will see they are different.

Re “-5.1923e+33”: -5.1923e+33 is tiny compared to 1.43441e+49. It is within the rounding interval of the display formatting by over ten orders of magnitude.

Subtraction occurs with binary representations of the decimal based numbers. What you are seeing is expected. If you look at the raw bits in x and y and see what happens when they are subtracted it will become much clearer what is happening and why.
